# JSP and servlets before Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

Hello I want to know if I can start learning Spring MVC even if I don't have any knowledge about JSP and Servlets, I used to program before in php and codeigniter. and now I want to start with java and I've heard that spring mvc is the most used framework out there.

Comment: You could but IMO it would be better learning JSP and Servlets before using any Java Web MVC framework.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on the web, starting with Oracle tutorials. E.g., http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/index.html (older Java 2 ee tutorials have better coverage of "low-level" techs, such as Servlets and JSPs).

Comment: @VictorSorokin JEE is currently in version 7, providing a link forom J2EE 4 is going almost 10 years to the past! This is the tutorial you should look for: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza just compare amount of coverage for Servlets/JSP/JSP EL between 1.4 tutorial and jee 7 tutorial... And basics are the same, except for async servlets, which are advanced topic for OP anyway.

Comment: @VictorSorokin Oracle even announced that it will be better moving to JSF and Facelets as the standard technology to develop Java web applications. That's why Servlets and JSP aren't covered in that tutorial. Anyway, you can look Java EE 6 tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/ to get a more decent Servlet tutorial than 8 years old tutorial...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can start learning Spring MVC.

The problem(s) will begin when you need to debug Things That Go Wrong, because you won't have the background knowledge of the components Spring is built upon.

That's not necessarily a bad thing, but it will make some things take longer than they might otherwise. For the most part, you can learn JSP as you go along. You don't need to learn about servlets specifically, but Spring MVC relies on the Servlet Specification, which talks about things like Java EE scoping (e.g., request, session, etc.), JSPs, filters, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The "V" in "MVC" stands for "View".  The Views in Spring MVC are all generally built on top of JSP's, which are in turn built on Servlets, so you will probably have to learn them at some point.  That being said, much of the Spring MVC tutorial material out there starts at the beginning, so you can learn the entire technology stack as you go, although you may want to have a JSP guide or reference handy, as the Spring MVC material won't get into the gory details of JSP syntax.

Comment: In fact, Spring MVC introduces some concepts like `@Controller` and `@Interceptor` that work over `DispatchServlet` and Servlet Filters, so you may not really learn servlets while learning Spring MVC. Also, even while learning Spring MVC views using JSP, you surely will encounter with outdated resources that will use scriptlets and show you that as the solution to your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is used a lot but so is Apache Struts and a dozen of other frameworks so you should also consider whether you want to stick to a specific framework.

From my experience refactoring Spring code to something else is quite difficult so once you go with Spring you must stay with it for a long time especially if your project is complex.

From my experience learning JSP and some JSF would be more than enough for most projects and you would have more time to consider frameworks.
I used Apache Struts a lot and now I got back to using only standard Java tools so JSP, JSF and JPA.